# Python PPTX library issue - Replacing image in slides ('SlidePart' object has no attribute 'related_parts')

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I use the PPTX library to automate the creation of a deck of slides on a weekly basis.
It was working really well until the last update of the library. As you can see below, I keep getting the following when updating the "image part" of the slides:

---

### AttributeError: 'SlidePart' object has no attribute 'related_parts'

---

Here is my function for the image replacement:

---

def replace_img_slide(prs, slide_nbr, shape_nbr, img_path):

```
slide = prs.slides[slide_nbr]
img = slide.shapes[shape_nbr]
try:
    imgPic = img._pic
except AttributeError:
    raise AttributeError(
        f"Error for slide: {slide_nbr}, shape: {shape_nbr}, path: {img_path}")
imgRID = imgPic.xpath('./p:blipFill/a:blip/@r:embed')[0]
imgPart = slide.part.related_parts[imgRID]

with open(img_path, 'rb') as f:
    rImgBlob = f.read()

# replace
imgPart._blob = rImgBlob

return prs
```

---

I found some related subject and I understood that the "related_parts" is now obsolete in the new version of the library but I did not find how to solve it. Do you think you can help me with that please ?

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `part.related_part(imgRID)` where you used to use `part.related_parts[imgRID]`.

The latest version exposes that method (internally) rather than expose a `dict`-like object just to do that one job.

Comment: Hi Scanny, it works, thanks a lot for that ! Also, I saw some of your answers in others topics related to similar issues, it was really helpful, so thanks again !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Reda. Be sure to accept an answer that resolves your question. That's how you say Thank You! on SO :) Just click on the checkmark to the left of the answer. That helps others locate an answer that worked and also gives you reputation points.